# How does the BSS segment manage to hold the details if it does not occupy any file size?

Tags: compiler-construction, linker, file-format, loader, elf

The ELF specification conveys that the .bss section does not occupy any file size. I wonder then, how does it manage to hold the details if it does not occupy any file size ? Please clarify me.

Answer (score 1):

You do not quote the section of the ELF specification, and when I searched I did not find "BSS" identified explicitly, so I'll quote the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) entry for BSS:

> In computer programming, the name .bss
>   or bss is used by many compilers and
>   linkers for a part of the data segment
>   containing statically-allocated
>   variables represented solely by
>   zero-valued bits initially (i.e., when
>   execution begins). It is often
>   referred to as the "bss section" or
>   "bss segment".

And the answer is simple: if you know that all values will be initialized to zero, there's no need to explicitly specify those values in the executable file.

Comment: Okay. I did an analysis and find using readelf that the File size was 130 bytes and Header size was 134 bytes. The difference of 4 bytes appear to match with the variables that shall go into the BSS. It appears that the difference of the Header size and the File size is equal to the BSS size (Variables that shall be part of the BSS). So, does it mean that the contents of the BSS are not part of the file, but part of the header ? Please clarify.

Comment: @S.Man - it might help to think of the header as a description of how the executable will look in memory, and the rest of the file as content to be stored accordingly. Other than that, I'm sorry, but your question doesn't make a lot of sense.